# Hosting Error in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Server Error in '/' Application.

Runtime Error

Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's  configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

pls help me..............

Answer (score 0):

Are you running on Vista or Win7?, is that on your local debuggin?.
Try to close the Visual Studio and re open it As Administrator.

If it doesn't work give me more details about it.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because some other error happened on the server, but your web application is configured not to show the exact error messages. (This is the default configuration.)

The reason: if on every thrown exception your app displayed the exact error message, basically anyone could know what the error is and may use this knowledge to exploit these errors. So basically, it is a security threat to show every error message.
Note that enabling debugging also decreases performance, so it is not recommended for a production app.

To turn on the showing of the error messages, follow the advice of the message you pasted here. Turn off CustomErrors and enable debugging mode in your Web.Config **temporarily**.
After this, you should be able to see the *real* error that causes your trouble.

When you're done fixing it, I recommend you to turn CustomErrrors back on, and disable debug mode.